# cifar10: implementing a model in keras but getting different accuracy than the article

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm not sure if stackoverflow is the correct place to ask this but here it goes:

I've read an paper called:
[Lets Keep it simple, Using simple architectures to outperform deeper and more complex architectures (2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06037.pdf)

According to this paper this architecture managed to achieve 94.75% accuracy 
but my implementation can achieve so far at maximum around 82% accuracy!

So my questions are:

- Regarding convolution layer stacking: is it ok to stack
  `conv->BatchNorm->Relu->(optional)max pooling` or the order is
  different?
- What I'm doing wrong here?

Notice I've tried various dropout values, and no dropouts( the reason for that is that I can get 100% accuracy on training set but 80% on test set(half of the test set)) also I've tried less dense layers, playing with learning rate
(increasing and as you can see - decreasing),

any suggestions would be greatly appriciated!

## Edit:

I've managed to improve it slightly with kernel weight initialization
(on each conv layer)

```
initializers.VarianceScaling(scale=1.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='normal')
```

but still it reach at most 86% accuracy on test set and if I introduce dropouts instead of increasing accuracy on test set(from my understanding dropouts should generalize the model better), still it's not the target accuracy that the article claims to achieve

Any help would be really appriciated!
my code:

```
def create_conv_block(X,filters = 64,kernel=[3,3],strides=[1,1],
                  repetition=1,withMaxPooling=True,
                  pool_kernel = [2,2], pool_strides = [2,2],
                  relualpha= 0,withDropOut=True,dropout_precent=0.5):

      conv_layer = X
      while(repetition > 0):
          conv_layer = layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, 
                                     kernel_size=kernel,
                                     strides=strides, padding='same')(conv_layer)
          conv_layer = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv_layer)
          conv_layer = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=relualpha)(conv_layer)
          if withMaxPooling:
              try:
                 conv_layer = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_kernel, 
                 strides=pool_strides)(conv_layer)
              except:
                 conv_layer = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_kernel, strides=pool_strides, padding='same')(
                conv_layer)

           if withDropOut:
                conv_layer = layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_precent)(conv_layer)

           repetition -= 1
      return conv_layer

def train(model_name):
#https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06037.pdf
  global inputs, res
  batch_size = 100
  input_shape = (32, 32, 3)
  inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

  block1 =  create_conv_block(inputs,withMaxPooling=False,withDropOut=True)
  block2 = create_conv_block(block1,filters=128,repetition=3,withDropOut=True)
  block3 = create_conv_block(block2,filters=128,repetition=2,withMaxPooling=False)
  block4 = create_conv_block(block3,filters=128,withDropOut=False)
  block5 = create_conv_block(block4,filters=128,repetition=2,withDropOut=True)
  block6 = create_conv_block(block5, filters=128, withMaxPooling=False,withDropOut=True)
  block7 = create_conv_block(block6, filters=128, withMaxPooling=False,kernel=[1,1],withDropOut=True)
  block8 = create_conv_block(block7, filters=128,kernel=[1,1],withDropOut=False)
  block9 = create_conv_block(block8, filters=128,withDropOut=True)
  block9 = create_conv_block(block9, filters=128,withDropOut=False)
  flatty = layers.Flatten()(block9)

  dense1 = layers.Dense(128,activation=activations.relu)(flatty)
  dense1 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dense1)
  dense1 = layers.Dense(512,activation=activations.relu)(dense1)
  dense1 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(dense1)
  dense2 = layers.Dense(512,activation=activations.relu)(dense1)
  dense1 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(dense2)
  dense2 = layers.Dense(512,activation=activations.relu)(dense1)
  dense3 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(dense2)


  res = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(dense3)
  model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=res)
  opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
  model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()
  reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau( factor=0.1, patience=5, min_lr=1e-10)
  keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file=model_name + '.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
  model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=100,
         validation_data=(test_X[:len(test_X) // 2], test_y[:len(test_X) // 2]),
         callbacks=[reduce_lr])
  model.save(model_name +'.h5')
  return model

name = 'kis_convo_drop'
model = train(name)
```

Comment: It has an official pytorch implementation as well, check that for details : https://github.com/Coderx7/SimpleNet_Pytorch

Answer (score 0):

It has official implementation on github, which you can see.
[SimpleNet](https://github.com/Coderx7/SimpleNet) is the official original `Caffe` implementation, and [SimpleNet in Pytorch](https://github.com/Coderx7/SimpleNet_Pytorch) is the official `Pytorch` implementation.
Apart from that, I noticed you are implementing a different architecture! your implementation is not the same as the one you are trying to implement.

- You are using `Dense` layers, where as in the `SimpleNet`, there is
  only `convolutional` layers and the only `dense` layer is the one for
  classification.
- You are using `Leaky ReLU` instead of `ReLU`.
- You are using `Adam` optimizer, whereas they used `Adadelta` in their
  implementation.